# How to get custom attribute value of ordered product?

Tags: magento2, product, orders, sales-order, custom-attributes

I have a Custom attribute name ( product string ) on Product in which i have save a string i want to get that custom attribute value for ordered product.

I have getting the ordered product by this code

```
 $orderId = 32;
 $order = $block->getOrderData($orderId);
 foreach ($order->getAllVisibleItems() as $_item) {
 echo $_item->getId();
    echo $_item->getSku();
    echo $_item->getName();
    echo $_item->getProductType();
    echo $_item->getQtyOrdered();
 echo "<pre>";print_r($_item->debug());
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get it with `$item->getProduct()->getData('attribute_code_here')`

But there is a problem.
Actually a few:

- Product may have been deleted
- the attribute value has been changed after the order was placed.
- the attribute may have been deleted

The best approach would be to save the value of the product attribute on the order item when the order is placed.
Here are some examples on how you can do that

- https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/205002/146
- https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/277601/146

Comment: Thanks for the response and help. Actually my requirement is different anyway thanks for the link. @Marius